# Dynamically sort JSON String based on given key

Tags: java, json, maven, kotlin

I would like to sort JSON strings based on some keys. My JSON can have multiple nested arrays. Is there any library/tool which sorts json?

The JSON object I receive, key is optional. For example, below request we are sorting **Actors** array first time using name then second time we are sorting using **child name** which is not present in second actor. I also want to sort  by sending key dynamically. In the example below, I used **name and child name**, likewise I should be able to send any key and sort.

Example:

```
{
  "Actors": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "age": 56,
      "Born At": "Syracuse, NY",
      "Birthdate": "July 3, 1962",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg",
      "wife": null,
      "weight": 67.5,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "hasGreyHair": false,
    },
    {
      "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "age": 53,
      "Born At": "New York City, NY",
      "Birthdate": "April 4, 1965",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg",
      "wife": "Susan Downey",
      "weight": 77.1,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "hasGreyHair": false,
      "children": [
                   {
                     "name":"Tom",
                      "age":15
                   },
                  {
                     "name":"Jerry"
                     "age":17
                   }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

First sort based on **name**, then sort based the sort children name array

**Output:**

```
{
  "Actors": [
    {
      "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "age": 53,
      "Born At": "New York City, NY",
      "Birthdate": "April 4, 1965",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg",
      "wife": "Susan Downey",
      "weight": 77.1,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "hasGreyHair": false,
      "children": [
                   {
                     "name":"Jerry"
                     "age":16
                   },
                  {
                     "name":"Tom"
                     "age":15
                   }
      ]
    },
 {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "age": 56,
      "Born At": "Syracuse, NY",
      "Birthdate": "July 3, 1962",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg",
      "wife": null,
      "weight": 67.5,
      "hasChildren": true,
      "hasGreyHair": false,
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to achieve this without creating any Iava objects. I don't have any control on JSON string coming based on input output JSON always changes.